# How can I change my usb from root to non-root permissions?

Tags: permissions, usb, root

`sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /media`

I connect a usb and mount it with previous command. This automatically puts all folders into "root ownership" and does not allow me to add any files or rename anything (though it had been before today, for some reason).

When I connect usb to desktop port and mount it 'without' a command, but by just clicking on the usb "icon" in file manager, it does NOT mount it as root and I have full access to the usb.

My efforts to change root permissions on a folder by folder basis: 
`sudo chmod 777 filename`; `sudo chown whoami:root filename`, or, `sudo chown root:root filename`. The folder becomes unlocked, but stays as 'root' permissions.

I also opened a terminal in the `/media` and did `sudo -s` and tried changing ownership there as well, but no change from root permissions.

Comment: Try sudo chown -v -R whoami:whoami /dev/sda1 and then sudo chmod -v -R 0777 /dev/sda1

Answer (score 1):

Without root permissions, you can't use mount like this, because pretty much anybody would be able to mount devices.

Non-privileged users can mount what you specify in /etc/fstab (you can read up on it here: https://superuser.com/questions/174776/modify-fstab-entry-so-all-users-can-read-and-write-to-an-ext4-volume)
Or you can use some wrapper around mount, like pmount (https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you to achieve your goals, but it is a good way to mount devices by command-line:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-label/NAME-OF-UFD
```